# OpenCV_Contrib builds in java with empty modules

Tags: opencv, cmake, mingw, cross-compiling, opencv-contrib

I have cross-compiled the opencv_contrib modules with opencv ([contrib github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib), [opencv github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv)) from c++ to java using cmake and the mingw cross compiler, but some of the built modules (line_descriptors and DPM) built as empty classes or classes with no usable methods. I could not find anyone else with the same problem, which suggests that I am doing something completely wrong in my build. I followed [this](https://zami0xzami.wordpress.com/2016/03/16/building-java-wrapper-for-opencv/) guide, but also disabled precompiled headers and commented out "#include reg.hpp" in reg.cpp and "#include datasets.hpp" in datasets.cpp. I can post my cmakevars file if needed, but I thought that might take up too much room.